# Boolean Modifyer dissapears if I delete object

Tags: modifiers

So after watching many tutorials on how to carve a 6 into the side of a cube (making dice), I followed steps to use the boolean modifyer to use a "6" object to carve into one face of the cube. All the tutorials say I should be able to delete the 6 object now. But when I do, the boolean modifyer deletes also. I end up with a blank cube again. Can someone help me? using the 2.8 blender. Also when I export as a stl file so i can put it in my 3d cutting software for the printer, it exports with all the numbers popping out of it, instead of boolean differences cut out of the cube.

Comment: I am not sure what tutorials you are watching, but you cannot delete the second object if you’re using a Boolean modifier unless you apply the modifier first.

Comment: Did you apply the boolean modifier?

Answer (score 1):

Blender keeps data of all modifier in temporary state until the modifier is applied. Simply putting at this stage you can do whatever you want with modifiers. So, blender is not sure at this point. You can delete the modifier and object will return back to it's base form. So, modifier data and object data are dependent to each other. If one is affected then other one will be affected too.

Coming to your scenario, Assume there is a cylinder going through the cube. Boolean modifier is configured to affect the cube. So, if cylinder is going through the cube it will make a hole in cube. When you delete the cylinder you will loose hole too. Because object data and cylinder data are dependent to each other. So, to save your hole **apply the modifier.** This will now make modifier data independent to modifier object and your target object will be modified. After you can delete the modifier object. in this case after applying modifier you can delete cylinder and you will have hole in cube.